# Rewrite Rule Causing too many redirects

Tags: apache, redirect

I am hosting multiple sites on Apache.
Wordpress configuration works perfectly, however configuring moodle site is causing too many redirects. This is my configuration in httpds-ssl.conf, please help.

#Word press config works perfectly
   
        DocumentRoot "c:/Apache24/htdocs/wp"
        ServerName http://uat.dummy.com.au:443

```
#Moodle causing too many redirects
<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerName uatlms.dummy.com.au
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/moodle/
    RedirectMatch ^/$ /moodle [L,R=301]
</VirtualHost>
```

I need moodle to be appended to URL, so the end result should be uatlms.dummy.com.au/moodle (that's why can't do DocumentRoot option)

Answer (score 0):

You mentioned a moodle site - if all requests to the site are to go to "/moodle", it is best to set `DocumentRoot` accordingly:

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerName uatlms.dummy.com.au
    DocumentRoot "c:/Apache24/htdocs/moodle"
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: I want to do this way, but the URL is now being used lots of places.. so need to have moodle in URL